# Host Unity server on replit?

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, replit

How can I host a dedicated Unity server on Replit? I just want to be able to export to Unity dedicated server, create a Repl, and be able to host a few players. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, try looking into https://www.photonengine.com/pun. Photon pun is on of the best free multiplayer product. Blackthornprod made a tutorial on this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93SkbMpWCGo

Comment: That's not the question I was asking. I'm already using Mirror for Unity but wanted to see if I could host the server on Replit.